# Intellij Idea 2016.3 complains about Android API level in non-Android module

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

My project is build by gradle and is structured into `android`, `core`, `desktop` modules. Where `android` is an Android module, but both `core` and `desktop` modules are java modules. The `core` is dependency of both `android` and `desktop`. When I write (in `desktop`):

```
Queue<P> qeueue= new ArrayDeque<P>();
```

The Idea complains:

> Cast from ArrayDeque to Queue requires API level 9 (current min is 1)

How can I avoid this complain? Disable the inspection on whole project doesn't seems right. I also do not want to convert the `desktop` to be an Android module.

Project's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // repositories 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "idea"
    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'my-app-name'
    }

    repositories {
        // repositories 
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        // some dependencies here
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        // some other dependencies here
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        // some dependencies here
    }
}
```

Core's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src/", "postprocessing/", "gl/", "math/", "experiment/"]

dependencies {
}
```

Desktop's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src/", "experiment/", "resources/"]
project.ext.mainClassName = "cz.plajt.wallp.hills.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from { configurations.compile.collect { zipTree(it) } }
    from files(project.assetsDir);

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}
dist.dependsOn classes

dependencies {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue for IntelliJ, and I am facing the same issue. I can't even get the project to compile in IntelliJ.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122904

There doesn't seem to be a workaround for this.